# IRC Bot, performance and scaling

Tags: python, performance, scaling, bots, irc

I have made a simple IRC bot for myself in python which works great, but now some friends has asked me if the bot can join their IRC channel too. Their IRC channels are very active, it is Twitch chat(IRC wrapper), which means a lot of messages. I want them to use my bot, but I have no idea how it will perform, this is my first bot I've made.

Right now my code is like this:
`Connect to IRC server & channel
 while true:
     Receive data from the socket (4096, max data to be received at once)
     do something with data received`

What changes should I do to make it perform better?
1. Should I have a sleep function in the loop?
2. Should I use threads?
3. Any general dos and don'ts?

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 1):

Threading is one option but it doesn't scale beyond a certain point (google Python GIC limitation).  Depending on how much scaling you want to do, then you need to do multi-process (launch multiple instances).

One pattern is to have a pool of worker threads that process a queue of things to do.  There's a lot of overhead to creating and destroying threads in most languages.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I tried to +1 but I need 15 rep before I can do it. What do you think is most efficient, using threads or just create a new instance of the script?

Comment: @LéoLeGall Threads, usually. But not much more than there are cores in the machine running the bot. With processes you would need some weird shared memory or a internal message queue (see rabbitmq or any other mq system) to sync up all instances, which might degrade it a bit. Plus, I believe any sufficiently powerful (say quad core) CPU can handle a Twitch stream chat. The bottleneck will be the internet most of the time!